# Can't see NAS storage size in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, nas, synology

I recently bought a Synology DS216+II. I have it mounted in windows 10 as a network drive, however a small detail annoys me.

When I view the drive in This PC like this, it dosent show the space in total and used on the NAS, like this does on the SSD' s in my system.
[image: Without mouse hovering]

I have to hover the mouse over it like this before it shows.

[image]

Is there a way to make it show it like the other drives in my system?

Comment: How did you mount it exactly?

Comment: I used the Synology Assistent tool to mount it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely caused by **the volume name being too long.** It seems like as soon as the name of the volume will extend to two lines in *Tiles view*, the capacity isn't shown:

[image]

Note how the capacity bar is in the third line as opposed to it being on the second line when the volume name is shorter, suggesting that the capacity text "drops out" of the frame.

**The solution is simply to give the volume a shorter name** that will fit in a single line in *Tiles view*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a Windows issue.

You can try disconnecting and remapping manually from within windows rather than synology apps.

[image: Network Mapped Drive]

**Disconnecting Mapped Drive**

Right click drive and click disconnect.

[image]

**Remap Drive Manually**

Double click my computer at the top of the screen click map network drive and follow instructions.

Windows 8:

Select the drive letter you had - Z:

- Folder will be the network location of the synology box -
  192.168.0.23
- Select Reconnect at sign-in
- Select Connect Using different credentials - these should be your
  synology box details should they differ from your windows account.

That should be it!